# What is this error in apt-get update: Unable to connect?

Tags: apt

**What is this error in apt-get update: Unable to connect**

My Internet connection is working and is fast (no proxy network),
but system fails when I try **apt-get update**:

```
    ~ $ Sudo apt-get update
[Sudo] password for amaponian:
Des: 1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Err: 2 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
   Unable to start the connection to ve.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5). - connect (101: The network is inaccessible) [IP: 2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5 80]
Err: 3 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
   Unable to start the connection to ve.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5). - connect (101: The network is inaccessible) [IP: 2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5 80]
Err: 4 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
   Unable to start the connection to ve.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5). - connect (101: The network is inaccessible) [IP: 2801: 82: 80ff: 8000 :: 5 80]
0% [1 InRelease 1.140 B / 102 kB 1%]
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy network?

Comment: [stupidly_logical](https://askubuntu.com/users/711664/stupidly-logical) No proxy network

Comment: And the rest of us who don't speak your language should???

Comment: [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george): Ok. I googletranslated it.

Comment: I think the server [http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/](http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) is down

Comment: You can temporaily change the messages to english by running this in your terminal session:  `LANG=C` . That way you have english output in the command line to show in your questions. This only affects your current terminal session.